# How can I copy a file in memory?

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I use the Image Picker package and I want to store some sort of cache of the original image that was load so that when a user want's to do the changes to the image he can just load that from cache. How would I do that?

```
  Future<void> pickImage(ImageSource source, {ImagePickerSettings settings}) async {
    settings = settings ?? ImagePickerSettings();
    _state = LoadingState.loading;
    notifyListeners();
    _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: source,
        maxWidth: settings.maxWidth,
        maxHeight: settings.maxHeight,
        imageQuality: settings.imageQuality);
    // _iamgeCache = a copy of _image
    _state = LoadingState.loaded;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/cache_image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cache_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cache_image#-readme-tab-)

> A Flutter plugin to load and cache network or firebase storage images with a retry mechanism if the download fails.
>
> This package supports the download of images from a standard network path and from a firebase storage gs path.
>
> Images are stored in the temporary directory of the app.

Example:

```
FadeInImage(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/placeholder.png'),
  image: CacheImage('gs://testing-9ea12.appspot.com/bake-1706051_1920.jpg')
)
```